# $ \text{cl}(\text{int}(A)) = \text{cl}(A)$ when A is convex

Tags: general-topology, convex-analysis

How can one prove that $ \text{cl}(\text{int}(A)) = \text{cl}(A)$, where $ A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ is convex?

I know that if $A$ is convex, $\text{int(A)}$ and $\text{cl(A)}$ are convex too.

I need help in $ \text{cl}(A) \subseteq    \text{cl}(\text{int}(A))$ part only.

Comment: Is this true? A line in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is convex, but has empty interior.

Comment: ok, I changed $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Well, a single point is convex in $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: In $\mathbb R$, the convex sets are very easily characterized. Per the above comment, you have to insist that $A$ have at least two points. For $\mathbb R^n$ you need to insist that there are $n+1$ points which are not all in the same $n-1$-plane.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1671444

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that the space is $\mathbb{R}^n$ with standard topology.

Your claim is false as it is, e.g. a single point is a convex set, but it's interior is empty, so $\mathrm{cl}(\{p\}) = \{p\} \neq \varnothing = \mathrm{cl}(\mathrm{int}(\{p\}))$. However, under the assumption that the interior is non-empty, that is $\mathrm{int}(A) \neq \varnothing$, your claim is true.

Let $x \in \mathrm{cl}(A)$ and let $y \in \mathrm{int}(A)$ be any point from the interior of $A$. We know that the interior $\mathrm{int}(A)$ is open, so there exists a ball $B(y,\delta) \subset \mathrm{int}(A)$. Moreover $A$ is convex, hence  for all $z \in B(y,\delta)$ we have $[xz] \subset A$. This in turn implies that $(xy] \subset \mathrm{int}(A)$, and finally $x \in \mathrm{cl}(\mathrm{int}(A))$.

The above implies $\mathrm{cl}(A) \subset \mathrm{cl}(\mathrm{int}(A))$, of course $\mathrm{cl}(\bullet)$ is monotone with respecto to $\subset$, therefore $\mathrm{cl}(A) = \mathrm{cl}(\mathrm{int}(A))$.

Have fun ;-)

Comment: Note also that a convex subset of a finite-dimensional Euclidean space has empty interior iff it is "flat", i.e., lies in some proper affine linear subspace.

Comment: What is $[xz]$? How do we know that $[xz]\subset A$? It looks like the "closed line segment" except that later you use a comma for a half-open interval.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews A typo. It is closed line segment, while $(xy]$ is half-open line segment. Thanks, fixed.

Comment: I guess the claim is also right when phrased with "relative interior" instead of "interior"?

Comment: @Dirk You need some minor tweaks, e.g. the ball in the proof has to have correct dimension, e.g. $B \cap \mathrm{relint}(A)$.